# My printer Canon LBP6000 is recognized by my ubuntu 20.04 but it still does not print

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, canon

So I am on this problem for quite some time now. After setting up my printer it does not print at all!

I am putting the necessary information out here for anyone to give me some leads

The output of `tail -f /var/log/syslog` when I connect the USB of the printer:

```
Inspiron-5577 update-notifier.desktop[116391]: /var/cache/apt/archives/lock:
Inspiron-5577 kernel: [ 5676.034111] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
Inspiron-5577 kernel: [ 5676.185754] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04a9, idProduct=271a, bcdDevice= 1.00
Inspiron-5577 kernel: [ 5676.185759] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Inspiron-5577 kernel: [ 5676.185762] usb 1-2: Product: Canon CAPT USB Device
Inspiron-5577 kernel: [ 5676.185765] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Canon
Inspiron-5577 kernel: [ 5676.185767] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 0000A1C5TEPh
Inspiron-5577 kernel: [ 5676.189182] usblp 1-2:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 33 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04A9 pid 0x271A
Inspiron-5577 systemd-udevd[116545]: 1-2: Process '/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxCreateUSBNode.sh 189 32 00' failed with exit code 1.
Inspiron-5577 systemd[1]: Started Configure Plugged-In Printer.
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: add usb-001-033
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: device devpath is /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: MFG:Canon MDL:LBP6000/LBP6018 SERN:- serial:0000A1C5TEPh
Inspiron-5577 kernel: [ 5682.147082] usblp1: removed
Inspiron-5577 kernel: [ 5682.151195] usblp 1-2:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 33 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04A9 pid 0x271A
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: URI contains USB serial number
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: URI match: usb://Canon/LBP6000/LBP6018?serial=0000A1C5TEPh
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: URI of detected printer: usb://Canon/LBP6000/LBP6018?serial=0000A1C5TEPh, normalized: canon lbp6000 lbp6018 serial 0000a1c5teph
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: ipp://Canone5f13e.local:631/ipp/print, normalized: ipp canone5f13e local 631 ipp print
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: ipps://EPSON869F11.local:631/ipp/print, normalized: ipps epson869f11 local 631 ipp print
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: ipps://EPSON869F11.local:631/ipp/print, normalized: ipps epson869f11 local 631 ipp print
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: usb://Canon/LBP6000/LBP6018?serial=0000A1C5TEPh, normalized: canon lbp6000 lbp6018 serial 0000a1c5teph
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: Queue ipp://localhost/printers/LBP6000-LBP6018 has matching device URI
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: Re-enabled printer ipp://localhost/printers/LBP6000-LBP6018
Inspiron-5577 udev-configure-printer: URI of print queue: cups-pdf:/, normalized: cups pdf
Inspiron-5577 systemd[1]: configure-printer@usb-001-033.service: Succeeded.
```

From the output above it seems it is correctly recognizing my printer.

The output of `lsusb` also gave:

`Bus 001 Device 033: ID 04a9:271a Canon, Inc. LBP6000`

The output `sudo lpstat -s`:

```
system default destination: LBP6000-LBP6018
device for Canon_MF633C_635C: ipp://Canone5f13e.local:631/ipp/print
device for EPSON_L605_Series: ipps://EPSON869F11.local:631/ipp/print
device for EPSON_L605_Series@EPSON869F11.local: ipps://EPSON869F11.local:631/ipp/print
device for LBP6000-LBP6018: usb://Canon/LBP6000/LBP6018?serial=0000A1C5TEPh
device for PDF: cups-pdf:/
```

So you can see it is the default set.

Output of `sudo lpinfo -v`:

```
network http
network https
network ipp
file cups-brf:/
direct hp
network ipps
serial serial:/dev/ttyS4?baud=115200
direct usb://Canon/LBP6000/LBP6018?serial=0000A1C5TEPh
direct hpfax
file cups-pdf:/
network beh
network lpd
network socket
network smb
```

Output of `ls -l /dev/usb/lp1` gives:

`crw-rw---- 1 root lp 180 /dev/usb/lp1`

The problem arises when I go to any text file and do the print option my syslog says:

`Inspiron-5577 kernel: [ 6061.033928] usblp1: removed`

and in the  settings of the ubuntu where the  driver is shown which is a simple Generic CUPS-PDF printer driver (w/options) there the job is shown to always be in the "processing" state.

I do not have any clue now, maybe the cups log will show  something? I am not sure.

Any leads after this will be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Output of `lpstat -t` as requested:

```
scheduler is running
system default destination: LBP6000-LBP6018
device for Canon_MF633C_635C: ipp://Canone5f13e.local:631/ipp/print
device for EPSON_L605_Series: ipps://EPSON869F11.local:631/ipp/print
device for EPSON_L605_Series@EPSON869F11.local: ipps://EPSON869F11.local:631/ipp/print
device for LBP6000-LBP6018: usb://Canon/LBP6000/LBP6018?serial=0000A1C5TEPh
device for PDF: cups-pdf:/
Canon_MF633C_635C accepting requests since Sunday 05 May 2019 11:10:25 AM
EPSON_L605_Series accepting requests since Friday 11 January 2019 12:12:31 PM
EPSON_L605_Series@EPSON869F11.local accepting requests since Friday 11 January 2019 12:16:03 PM
LBP6000-LBP6018 accepting requests since Tuesday 08 March 2022 10:26:49 AM
PDF accepting requests since Tuesday 08 June 2021 02:34:05 PM
printer Canon_MF633C_635C is idle.  enabled since Sunday 05 May 2019 11:10:25 AM
printer EPSON_L605_Series is idle.  enabled since Friday 11 January 2019 12:12:31 PM
printer EPSON_L605_Series@EPSON869F11.local is idle.  enabled since Friday 11 January 2019 12:16:03 PM
printer LBP6000-LBP6018 now printing LBP6000-LBP6018-20.  enabled since Tuesday 08 March 2022 10:26:49 AM
    Sending data to printer.
printer PDF is idle.  enabled since Tuesday 08 June 2021 02:34:05 PM
LBP6000-LBP6018-18      anonymous         1024   Tuesday 08 March 2022 12:39:55 AM
LBP6000-LBP6018-20      aaryan          136192   Tuesday 08 March 2022 01:30:24 AM
```

Actually I do not know what the 2 different "anonymous" and "aaryan" are for 18 and 20 though.

Comment: Please show output of `lpstat -t`.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings done, please check, thanks!

Comment: Check output of `lpstat -l -p LBP6000-LBP6018`. BTW, those last two items are print jobs.